# Parse error 200 Json ajax webapp2

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, webapp2

I have a AJAX call from jQuery

```
function Admin_Ajax_pop_rows(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    variable1= 'none';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/someurl",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({"variable1": variable1})
        })
        .success(function(data){
            alert('success response: ' + data + ' number of rows : ');
        })
        .done(function(data){
            alert ('rows : ' + data.return_rows);
            MakeTablejQuery(data);
        })
        .fail(function(error){
            alert('error status is : ' + error.status + ' text: ' + error.statusText + ' response     text : ' + error.responseText);
        });
    });
}
```

And in my Python server code I have

```
def post(self):
    user_key = ndb.Key(self.user_model,'value')
    user_key_parent = user_key.parent()
    user_query = self.user_model.query(ancestor = user_key_parent).order(ndb.GenericProperty(sort_field))
    query_data = user_query.fetch(i, projection=[ndb.GenericProperty('name'),ndb.GenericProperty('last_name'),ndb.GenericProperty('email_address')])
    table_prop_data = { 'return_rows': 9 , 'return_cols' : 8}
    return_table_prop_data = []
    return_table_prop_data = json.dumps(table_prop_data)
    return_data = []
    return_data = json.dumps([dict(p.to_dict(), **dict(id=p.key.id())) for p in query_data],default = date_handler)
    self.response.headers['content-type']=("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    self.response.out.write(return_data)
    self.response.headers['content-type']=("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    self.response.out.write(return_table_prop_data)
```

I get an error of "200" with status of "parse error"

JSONLint shows a JSON error

```
Parse error on line 74:
    ...662981951488    }]{    "return_cols":
    ---------------------^
    Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

I am using Webapp2 on GAE

Per Felix' suggestion I tried to create a dictionary using the following -

```
return_data = json.dumps({'table_props': dict(table_prop_data), 'query_data' : [dict(p.to_dict(), **dict(id=p.key.id())) for p in query_data],default = date_handler})
```

I am getting a syntax error. Please help me fix this. Here is my date_handler function. I need this to take care of the Datetime fields in my query.

```
def date_handler(obj):
    return obj.isoformat() if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat') else obj
```

Comment: By the way, 200 is not an error code. That is HTTP OK code.  From AJAX caller's perspective the HTTP call WAS successful, it's just that the JSON is malformed as noted in answer by @FelixKling below.

Comment: Mike - Agree. The JSON reaches my javascript and in my Chrome Developer Tools I am able to the list of objects (query_data) and the variables (table_prop_data). But the AJAX returns with a .fail and I am not able to execute the function under .success. You are correct the ajax call fails because the json is malformed.

Comment: Regarding your syntax error, it seems you are not closing the dictionary passed to `json.dumps` properly. You are missing a `}` after `]` in `],default=...)`. The error message should have already guided you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to try to return two individual JSON blobs in a single response. That can't work, as you can see by the jsonlint error. The whole response must be one single JSON blob.

Comment: Can you please help how to create on single JSON blob out of these two? Do I have to merge / append the list of objects (query_data) and the key-values (table_prop_data). I am struggling here. Any help is greatly appreciated. I need to get both these data sets (query_Data and table_prop_data) to my javascript and access them after the successful AJAX call.

Comment: Either create a dictionary or a list and stringify it: `json.dumps({'table_props': table_prop_data, 'query': [...]})`. You can combine the two values in any way that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Let me try that and get back to you.